# Sum of Digits of a Five Digit Number in c?Could you spot the error?

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement, scanf

BTW I know that's not the most efficient way to do it but if I wanted to do it like I did, what did I do incorrectly? The task was: *Given a five digit integer, print the sum of its digits.*

Constraint: 10000 <= n <= 99999
Sample Input: `10564`
Sample Output: `16`

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int n, sum;
    int remainder_array[4] = { n % 1000; n % 100, n % 10, n };
    int digits_array[4];

    scanf("%d", &n);
    // Complete the code to calculate the sum of the five digits on n.
    if (10000 <= n && n <= 99999) {
        else if (remainder_array[0] = 0) {
            digits_array[0] = (n - remainder_array[0]) / 1000; 
            n = remainder_array[1];
        } else if (remainder_array[1] != 0) {
            digits_array[1] = (n - remainder_array[1]) / 100;
            n = remainder_array[2];
        } else if (reminder_array[2] != 0) {
            digits_array[2] = (n - remainder_array[2]) / 10;
            n = remainder_array[3];
        } else if (reminder_array[3] != 0) {
            digits_array[3] = n - remainder_array[3];
        } else {
            printf("%d", n / 1000);
        }
        sum = digits_array[0] + digits_array[1] + digits_array[2] + digits_array[3];
        printf("%d", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Helpfun hint: turn on and mind your compiler warnings.

Comment: Undefined behavior for using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- you initialize `remainder_array` from the value of `n` **before** reading the value of `n`.
- the initializer is incorrect: the separator should be `,`, not `;`.
- you start the statement inside the `if` body with `else`, which is a syntax error.
- the test `if (remainder_array[0] = 0)` sets `remainder_array[0]` to `0` and evaluates to false.
- `remainder_array` is misspelt a `reminder_array`

Your approach is fine, but you should intialize `remainder_array` with the actual remainders (5 of them), after reading and checking `n`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;

    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && 10000 <= n && n <= 99999) {
        int remainder_array[5] = { n / 10000, n / 1000 % 10, n / 100 % 10, n / 10 % 10, n % 10 };
        int sum = remainder_array[0] + remainder_array[1] + remainder_array[2] +
                  remainder_array[3] + remainder_array[4];
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you don't actually need this `remainder_array`, you could just write:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;

    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && 10000 <= n && n <= 99999) {
        int sum = n / 10000 + n / 1000 % 10 + n / 100 % 10 + n / 10 % 10 + n % 10;
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a more readable and more generic version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;

    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && 10000 <= n && n <= 99999) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (n >= 10) {
            sum += n % 10;
            n = n / 10;
        }
        sum += n;
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor: We could also note that `remainder_array` was spelled as `reminder_array` in some places. Also, you increased its size from `4` to `5`

Comment: `int sum = n / 10000 + n / 1000 % 10 + n / 100 % 10 + n / 10 % 10 + n % 10;` error prone. I would discourage beginners from using it. Better repeat simple task 5 times

Comment: @P__J__: I added a third version for beginners.

Comment: Thanks for adding your 3rd example with the `while` loop. Not seeing _somebody_ posting this simple and obvious clean version was making me crazy [I didn't post it because OP wanted the more complex version working] but since you already fixed OP's version, it fine to show a progression of answers from OP to "pro grade" [which I sometimes do myself] +1

Comment: @CraigEstey is while version any better than for loop version (as in my answer). If yes explain your opinion.

Comment: @P__J__ I guess you were a victim of TL;DR where TL was "too late here for rational thought" ;-) and I just didn't notice your answer. So, +1.

Answer (score 1):

your algorithm is far too complicated, It can be done much easier way without arrays.

```
int sumof5LSD(int x)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int digit = 1; digit <=5; digit++)
    {
        result += abs(x % 10);
        x /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("SUM: %d", sumof5LSD(10564));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/bcdM8P

or if you are not allowed to use loops:

```
int sumof5LSD(int x)
{
    int result = 0;
    result += abs(x % 10);
    x /= 10;
    result += abs(x % 10);
    x /= 10;
    result += abs(x % 10);
    x /= 10;
    result += abs(x % 10);
    x /= 10;
    result += abs(x % 10);

    return result;
}
```

It is good to use functions to perform similar tasks.

Version with scanf

```
int main(void)
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("SUM of 5 digits of %d = %d", n, sumof5LSD(n));
}
```

it will also calculate the sum of 5 digits of the negative number

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the errors and modifications what @P_J_ and @chqrlie has mentioned I have noticed some major logical errors and misunderstanding of a basic concept in your code(assuming that first else if is replaced by if)
you have given else if statement repeatedly, now what this does is that whenever the first condition it encounters is true it executes the block inside and exits from the branch i.e remaining statements after else if is not executed, this might cause a major logical error in your program.

```
 if (10000 <= n && n <= 99999) {
        else if (remainder_array[0] = 0) {
            digits_array[0] = (n - remainder_array[0]) / 1000; 
            n = remainder_array[1];
        } else if (remainder_array[1] != 0) {
            digits_array[1] = (n - remainder_array[1]) / 100;
            n = remainder_array[2];
        } else if (reminder_array[2] != 0) {
            digits_array[2] = (n - remainder_array[2]) / 10;
            n = remainder_array[3];
        } else if (reminder_array[3] != 0) {
            digits_array[3] = n - remainder_array[3];
        } else {
            printf("%d", n / 1000);
        }
```

[image]

Now in this picture if you notice the output you can see that the digits_array[1-3] are 0 this is because of the reason mentioned above(it is zero cause I have initialized it beforehand) hence the sum is zero.

And the second logical error is that you are dividing a 5 digit number by 1000 this will give you thousand's place i.e in example 10546 this step will result in 10 this is wrong, take another example 12233 not the sum for the digits should result in 11 but you will get 20 because when you divide 12233 by 1000 the first value of digits_array (digit_array[0]) is 12 so the entire output goes wrong. so to correct this divide it by 10000 (only for this program statement as it has 5 digits).

But still, if you wish to continue without changing the algorithm then this code should work fine.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int n, sum;
    int digits_array[5]={0}; //5 because it is a five digit number.
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int remainder_array[] = { n % 1000, n % 100, n % 10, n };//This is still a useless array this is kept so as to enter if.
    // Complete the code to calculate the sum of the five digits on n.
    if (10000 <= n && n <= 99999) {
        if (remainder_array[0] != 0) {
            digits_array[0] = (n) / 10000;//subtracting n with contents of remainder_array added to the complexity of the algorithm so took out the statement.
            n =(n)%10000;
        } if (remainder_array[1] != 0) {
            digits_array[1] = (n) / 1000;
            n =(n)%1000;
        } if (remainder_array[2] != 0) {
            digits_array[2] = (n) / 100;
            n =(n)%100;
        } if (remainder_array[3] != 0) {
            digits_array[3] = (n)/10;
            n=(n)%10;
        } 
          digits_array[4]=n;//the last element of the number 
        }
        sum = digits_array[0] + digits_array[1] + digits_array[2] + digits_array[3]+digits_array[4];
        printf("%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Note: This program is not the best way and some changes are made refer to other answers for a more effective code and get the basics right before going to nested if condition.

**Enjoy coding**